# Outlook msg format - how to construct __nameid_version1.0 stream

Tags: outlook, pst, msg

I have been working with an open-source project called pstsdk up on codeplex. My current task is to generate msg files from the pst. Mostly I have been successful but to make it complete I want to be able to generate the named property stream __nameid_version1.0. Does anyone have any ideas about the algorithm that generates the named property stream? I have posted this question to codeplex with no response and I have not found any MS documentation that details the algorithm.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Most people don't know it, but many of the file formats and protocols are completely documented by Microsoft.  They are all in PDF format.  Here is the MSG File Format: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc463912%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx

Mapping the named properties is kind of complicated, but it is laid out starting at Section 2.2.3 Named Property Mapping Storage.

You will see lots of references to some of the other documents, so you'll probably want to download them all to have locally: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=115073

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I reread the links above and have finally cracked the nut.